# Analyzing spark executor memory dump { After few days yarn container runs of out memory}

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm, spark-streaming

I am working on spark 1.3 and my application is a spark streaming application. I use yarn as resource manager. My application runs fine for few days and then spark job loses executor periodically. When I look at node_manager logs, I found a exception:

```
containerId XXXX is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 11.1 GB of 11 GB physical memory used; 13.4 GB of 23.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

My questions for this exception are follow:

1. I understand 11G would memory of executor running. But i set 10G as executor memory in spark-defaults.conf. Then how is 11G assigned to executor and what is the virtual memory mentioned here ?
2. Is there any tools or way i can see on heap and off heap memory dump when container runs out of memory or is there a way I could connect remotely to container JVM and see which objects are causig memory leaks.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot about `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` property:

> spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead
>
> executorMemory * 0.10, with minimum of 384    The amount of off-heap
>   memory (in megabytes) to be allocated per executor. This is memory
>   that accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other
>   native overheads, etc. This tends to grow with the executor size
>   (typically 6-10%).

In your case it's approximately 1G additionally.

2. You can use common java properties for OOM: `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and `-XX:HeapDumpPath=..` . Just add these properties by `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`.

Comment: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError would help, however, the dump is saved by default to the current working directory of the task, which in Hadoop’s case is a temporary scratch space managed by the framework and it would become inaccessible once the task completes. How will you solve such an issue?

Comment: The `HeapDumpPath` argument would allow specifying a more permanent location.